# Oxyplot column series - Add items by using a loop

Tags: c#

I have a oxyplot column series which I have masked as a histogram using a linear axis. I get my values from a list called frequency with 20 elements.

I wonder if there is a smarter way to do this:

```
this.Items = new Collection<Item>
{ 
    new Item {Label = "1", Value=frequency[0]},
    new Item {Label = "2", Value=frequency[1]},
    new Item {Label = "3", Value=frequency[2]},
    ...
    new Item {Label = "18", Value=frequency[17]},
    new Item {Label = "19", Value=frequency[18]},
    new Item {Label = "20", Value=frequency[19]},
};
```

I have tried to create a for-loop inside like this:

```
this.Items = new Collection<Item>
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Items.Add(new Item { Label = i.ToString(), Value = frequency[i]});
    }
};
```

But it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Put the for-loop *outside* the object initialiser.

Comment: Create empty Collection object. Execute loop from 1 to 20, in the loop collectionObj.Add(...); After the loop this.Items=collectionObj;.

Comment: Also, for the future - "does not work" is not an adequate problem description. Please include the (in this case) compiler error you get, and for runtime errors, whatever exception you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the for loop in the object initializer.

1. Create the collection.

   ```
   this.Items = new Collection<Item>();
   ```
2. Populate it:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++)
   {
       Items.Add(new Item { Label = i.ToString(), Value = frequency[i] });
   }
   ```